# Confusion about perl reference precedence

Tags: perl

I must simply ask what is the difference between the two here ?

`${$rarray[1]}`   vs   `${$rarray}[1]`

I understand `${$rarray}[1]`   but I really cannot life of me understand `${$rarray[1]}`  ??

Comment: You might like the "Circumfix notation" section in https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/

Comment: Module B::Deparse often can help to figure out what interpreter thinks about given data structure. Try this for both of your snippets: perl -MO=Deparse,-p -E'${$rarray}[1]'

Comment: %{   $data->{$a}   }   Btw, is this hash of hash?

Comment: hmm I get

perl -MO=Deparse,-p -E'%{data->{$a}}'
use feature 'current_sub', 'evalbytes', 'fc', 'say', 'state', 'switch', 'unicode_strings', 'unicode_eval';
%{$data{$a};};

Comment: And yet another useful module:  perl -MData::Dumper -E'$data = { a => { b => 2 } }; say Dumper $data'

documentation for references: perldoc perlref

Comment: something like @$A{ @col }      is this array of array?

Comment: @hanabbs No. `$array[0][0]` is an element in an array of arrays. All you have to remember about complex data structures is that when you want to add another level in a data structure in Perl, you add a *reference* to that data structure. For example, `@foo = ([ 'a','b' ], \@bar)` creates an array of arrays, and in both cases just adds a reference to another array in the `@foo` array. Same goes for hashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`${$rarray[1]}` is the second element of an array `$rarray[1]` being dereferenced into a scalar by `${ ... }`.

`${$rarray}[1]` is the second element in the array `@$rarray`.

It can be easier to see if you add some whitespace:

```
${   $rarray[1]   }        # @rarray is defined somewhere
${   $rarray      }[1]     # $rarray is an array reference
```

As a way to visualize it, imagine this

```
my $aref = $rarray[1];    # copy array ref
print ${ $aref };         # dereference $aref
```